# Where to store sensitive data for ElectronJS app?

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder

I have an ElectronJS app with an Angular6 renderer.  My Angular6 portion has consumer keys and secrets on it to call a Java REST API.  Because the app is installable a Electron desktop app of course, users could see the consumer key/secret.  Is there a way to protect these sensitive values on the Angular/ElectronJS side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear in your question whether you're storing this sensitive data on Angular's side or Electron's side.
In any case, you're not supposed to store sensitive data such as API keys and whatnot inside Angular or any front-end framework, as all of these files are going to be visible by the browser once built.

What you need to do is make sure you store such files in your back-end (e.g. `.env` file), or in the case of ElectronJS, there's [this simple technique](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/environment-variables) explained by Electron's DOCs.

Comment: Yes, I'll be storing them in Angular's side...the Angular that's packaged along with my Electron app that is and using the environment.ts files there.

Comment: How does this work in production though? Electron has production environment variables, but you can't create your own and they're mostly booleans anyway.